# uibutton only showing in the newly added uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I'm stuck at showing the uibutton *removeSticker, please help.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.width, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.height)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
[imageView setImage:_imagePicker.selectedImage];
[holderView addSubview:imageView];

removeSticker = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
removeSticker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32);
[removeSticker setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel-disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[removeSticker addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[holderView addSubview: removeSticker];
[removeSticker setHidden: YES];

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
[longPressRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];

[stickerView addSubview:holderView];

}

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
UIView *holderView = [(UIButton *)sender superview]; [holderView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The uibutton *removeSticker only appears on the latest added uiview *holderView, if I want to edit the previously added once, nothing occurs. Please help, thanks a lot.

```
-(void)longPress:(id)sender {
[removeSticker setHidden:NO];
}
```

Please check the attached screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moMOj.png

For the screenshot above, bottle and watermelon are `*holderView`.
I've added the bottle first, and then added the watermelon afterwards, however when I click on the bottle, `[removeSticker setHidden:NO];` shows up in the watermelon instead of the bottle.

`[removeSticker setHidden:NO];` only shows up on the latest newly added `*holderView`.

Comment: What do you mean by "only appears on the latest added uiview *holderView" ? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a):

"A view can have only one superview at the same time."

So if you add a view as a subview to another view, the subview will be removed from its previous superview and added to the new one. (see the addSubview method's documentation).

(consider thinking about why UIView has a single @property of type UIView *superview, and not an NSArray named superviews [in plural]).

**Edit**: if you actually want to have multiple views in multiple superviews, you'll have to create multiple instances of your UIView and add the multiple instances to the various superviews. You'll also want to take care of the corresponding UIView instances, so you may add them to an NSArray and manage that aeray using an NSDictionary.